# $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\cos(\epsilon-n\frac{\pi}{2})}{\epsilon^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

We were doing generalized integrals in class and this integral came out. I tried using integration by parts and got something repeating. We're gonna let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $x\rightarrow\infty$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-\cos t}{t}dt=\Big[\frac{-\sin t}{t}\Big]_{\epsilon}^{x}+\Big[\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\Big]_{\epsilon}^{x}+\Big[\frac{2\sin t}{t^3}\Big]_{\epsilon}^{x}+\Big[\frac{-6\cos t}{t^4}\Big]_{\epsilon}^{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^x\frac{-24\cos t}{t^5}dt$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!\cos{(t-n\frac{\pi}{2})}}{t^n}\Big]^x_{\epsilon}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!\Big(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos(x-n\frac{\pi}{2})}{x^n}-\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\cos(\epsilon-n\frac{\pi}{2})}{\epsilon^n}\Big)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(n-1)!\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\cos(\epsilon-n\frac{\pi}{2})}{\epsilon^n}$$
The first limit is $0$ by squeeze theorem but what about the second one, I don't know how to start.
Please share your work, thank you for your time!

Comment: This integral is divergent

Comment: Alright, too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Before starting, you can notice the problem close to $t=0$ since
$$-\frac{\cos (t)}{t}=-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^3}{24}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ So, if you try to integrate between $0$ and $\epsilon$, you see the problem.

Sooner or later, you will learn that you face the problem of [the cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html)
and that
$$-\int_x^\infty \frac{\cos (t)}{t}\,dt=\text{Ci}(x)$$ Close to $x=0$, its series expansion is 
$$\text{Ci}(x)=\gamma+\log(x)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\left(-x^2\right)^k}{2 k \,(2 k)!}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$\int_0^{\arccos{(0.5)}}\frac{\cos{(t)}}{t} dt\gt \int_0^{\arccos{(0.5)}}\frac{0.5}t dt\to\infty$$

Comment: Well, the integral diverges, but I am getting the sum to be equal 0..

Comment: I can't see a mistake in its expression though.

Comment: Well just $\left[\frac{\cos{(t)}}{t^2}\right]_\epsilon^x$ alone diverges to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty,\epsilon\to0$ so I don't think the following sum is really relevant.

Comment: @Luyw the issue is that there will always be a divergent integral after that summation. You cannot just take the summation infinitely and forget the latter integral that will always be present after the summation.

Comment: as $x\to \infty$ no probs with that, but I couldn't compute it as $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: Because that is what causes divergence...

Comment: granted for the integral, I meant the limit!

Comment: The same goes for the limit and every limit in question so far

Comment: thank you Peter :)